# Pyglet sound won't load, the ".load" gives an AttributeError but it worked the day before

Tags: python, audio, pyglet

I was attempting to make a video player using a mix of Tkinter and Pyglet to run the sound. And it worked...for once. I opened up the file today, ran it to see where I'd left off from when I'd finished last night and...

```
shop = pyglet.load('shop.wav')
AttributeError: module 'pyglet' has no attribute 'load'
```

And it worked just last night...

So I tried making a file with just the sound test and the same thing happened. I followed the docs *exactly*.

```
import pyglet

shop = pyglet.load('shop.wav')
voice = pyglet.Player()
voice.queue(shop)

voice.play()
pyglet.app.run()
```

*it worked just last night*

I re-installed Pyglet, no effect.

Does anyone have any idea what's wrong?

Comment: remove the `from pyglet import *` line...

Comment: No effect... :/

Comment: It was meant to be an audio file, according to Pyglet's docs... ```source = load('background_music.mp3')```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ".wav" file can be loaded by the `pyglet.media` module width [`pyglet.media.load`](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/stable/programming_guide/media.html):

```py
shop = pyglet.media.load('shop.wav')
```

respectively

```py
from pyglet.media import load

shop = load('shop.wav')
```